# Calculating Percentile in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have around 4 gigs worth of JSONs in my HDFS over which I've created a Hive table using a JSON Serde. Final data is expected to be around 25GB.

The table has 10 columns, all int. I need to calculate percentile rank for each 'cell' and insert in a separate column for each column. 
So my final result would be:

```
col1 col2 col3 .... col10 perCol1 perCol2 ... perCol10
100  200  123       423   82.44   58.22       18.42
```

So `18.42` in `perCol10` is the percentile of `423` in `col10` with respect to the entire `col10`.

Previously I was doing the same with a (much) smaller dataset in-memory with a NumPy array. But being new to HiveQL and databases in general, I don't really know where to start, so any help or pointers would be appreciated!

From some initial research, `cume_dist` seems to be of interest but I can't understand how to use it in my use case.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

percentiles are direct function in Hive ... But the percentile are calculated for the continuous distribution ... for discrete distributions ... i have a simple query .... 
    sort_array(collect_list(cast(Tx_fragment_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))))        [cast(floor    (size(collect_list(Tx_fragment_count)) * 95/100) as int)] AS `95th Per Tx_fragment_cnt`

The above query will calculate 95 percentile value .... for a column Tx_fragment_count which is string column